# Likelihood function of a Beta-Normal distribution

Tags: python, scoring, numerical

I'm going over a paper regarding the calculation of [credit scoring By Kalkbrener and Onwunta](http://kalkbrener.at/Selected_publications_files/KalkbrenerOnwunta10.pdf). In the article, they derive the following Likelihood function, in order to find the MLE for $R^2$:

[image] (Equation 19 in the article)

with $N(\psi)$ being the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), and

$$
\bar{p}_{R^2}(\psi) = N\left(\frac{c-\sqrt{R^2}\psi}{\sqrt{1-R^2}}\right).
$$

In the paper, the authors say that one can calculate the Likelihood function via numerical integration. I wanted to know is there any way to do this using python, then optimizing the Likelihood function in order to derive the ML estimator for $R^2$. I'd be glad for a code or a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to go here might be to use the auto-diff tools developed for neural networks. I tend to use JAX lately, so JAX+optax will do the optimization provided you can write the likelihood in a useable form. As it stands, I am not quite sure what your integral means. Your measure is $N$, does it mean that the integral is

$$
\int p^d \cdot\left(1-p\right)^{n-d} dN=
\int_0^1 N^d \cdot\left(1-N\right)^{n-d}dN=B\left(d+1,\,n-d+1\right)
$$

where $B$ is the [Beta-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)? If this is the case, it is not clear how you would want to proceed, since $R^2$ is no longer affecting the likelihood.

If it happens that integral is more complex then you can either approximate the integral with something like trapezium rule and still use JAX+optax, or you can use some Bayesian libraries, like numpyro, to sample the density under the integral, and then marginalize that. If you only have two/three params, e.g. $c$, $\psi$, $R^2$ you might be able to simply brute-force that (evaluate likelihood at all possible combinations of these params, and pick the largest one - numpy.meshgrid will then suffice).

---

Addendum

here is a snippet that shows how to package integral into a differentiable function in JAX

```py
import jax


import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.scipy as jsp
import jax.lax as jl

psi_arr = jnp.linspace(-100, 100, 2000)

f = lambda a, b, n, d, psi: jnp.exp(-psi**2/2)*(jsp.special.erf(a+b*psi)**d)*((1-(jsp.special.erf(a+b*psi))**(n-d)))
int_f = lambda p, n, d: jnp.trapz(y=f(p['a'], p['b'], n, d, psi_arr))

params = {'a': 5.0, 'b': 1.0}

jax.value_and_grad(lambda p: int_f(p, n=5, d=1))(params)
```

Output is:

```
(Array(0.00360544, dtype=float64),
 {'a': Array(-0.01209422, dtype=float64, weak_type=True),
  'b': Array(0.03792493, dtype=float64, weak_type=True)})
```

Because it is differentiable you can then use optimisers such as optax.adam to optimize for `a` and `b`

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those tools up!

Anyways, I don't think you can integrate the L(R^2|d) function the way you did. Notice that $\bar{p}_{R^2}$ has a linear function in inside the N, so the integration by substitution isn't easily done. Also note that if it were true, L(R^2|d) was independent of R^2...

Comment: That goes back by what you mean by the integral. What does $\int \dots dN$ mean? Once this is clear, the rest should be doable. Good luck

Comment: $\int ... dN \equiv \int ... \cdot\exp(-\psi^2/2)d\psi$.

Comment: But then your integral is simply a sum of various powers of normal distribution. This can be integrated analytically. Then you can apply MLE using JAX+optax

Comment: @AlexTeush  for your attention.........

Comment: I think that by "normal distribution" you mean "error function". that's what N stands for. And I don't think you can integrate it analytically (or at least I don't think that a simple integration by substitution will work here) since inside the brackets "N()" it's not $\psi$ but an affine map of it...
If you're willing to try out analytically calculating its integral there's a comprehensive list of erf integrals in the link:
https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf

Comment: @AlexTeush, I see, so N is error function. In this case the second part of my comment applies. Either approximate integral with trapezium rule - do it using JAX primitives and you will be able to run optimizers against it, brute-force it or use numpyro to sample from underneath the integral. I would probably go with the first method.

Comment: @AlexTeush, see the code above for how to package it, then simply follow https://optax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optax-101.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Highly appreciated!